# Is there a command line interface for slack?

Tags: command-line, chat

I am a user of slack https://slack.com/

I think the desktop client is useful, but sometimes I am working on servers. There is also a browser interface and android and iPhone Clients.
My objective is to read and write messages form a command line, for example inside a server environment.

So is there a command line interface frontend for slack?

Comment: Can we migrate this to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no full-fledged command line interface that I know of, but there is an [API](https://api.slack.com/), so in principle anybody could start writing one. [Slackcat](https://github.com/rlister/slackcat) is a first step in that direction.

A potential alternative approach might be installing a text-mode IRC or XMPP client on your servers, and using the [Slack/IRC/XMPP gateway](https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201727913-Connecting-to-Slack-over-IRC-and-XMPP).

EDIT/UPDATE: This answer is clearly outdated now – see the comments and other answers.

Comment: There is a basic client called Yfiton: https://github.com/yfiton/yfiton

Comment: There is also slacktee, which runs from the command line and the only requirement is `curl`: https://github.com/course-hero/slacktee

Comment: If you're just looking to send a simple message, you're probably better off using Slack's incoming webhook and `curl`. No cli necessary.

Answer (score 24):

I use this one.  Try https://github.com/candrholdings/slack-cli

To install, type

```
npm install -g slack-cli
```

To send a message,

```
slackcli -t <Slack token> -g <Slack group name> -m "Hello, World!"
```

To send a file,

```
slackcli -t <Slack token> -g <Slack group name> -f <File name>
```

To send from standard input,

```
cat anyFile.txt | slackcli -t <Slack token> -g <Slack group name> -c
```

You can even set the token as environment variable.

```
SET SLACK_TOKEN=<Slack token>
slackcli -g yourGroupName -m "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: Does this support attachments?

Comment: Tokens are disabled now by slack because they recommend slack apps or webhooks for security reasons I'm guessing. So this answer no longer works :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's Slacker, a CLI for Slack using PHP. You'll need your own Slack api token and adjust the configs: https://github.com/TidalLabs/Slacker

Comment: A possible alternative: https://github.com/erroneousboat/slack-term